# Asking User To Enable Push Notifications on first launch

Tags: ios, push-notification

I read from a critique someone posted about my app that it is not good practice to ask the user to enable push notifications on their first launch. I never saw a problem with doing this, but I wanted to hear others views on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, it is best to prompt them for notifications (or any other permissions for that matter) when they can see how it will benefit them. Many times, users won't know why you want to send them push notifications on the first launch. Apple talks about this in their human interface guidelines for iOS:

> “Ask permission at app startup only if your app can’t perform its primary function without the user’s data. People won’t be bothered by this if it’s obvious that the main function of your app depends on knowing their personal information.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “iOS Human Interface Guidelines.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/pyfv0.l

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ask a user for permissions of any type is the first time it is actually needed for the app. (i.e for a camera, when the camera screen is loaded)

As for push notifications, if there is a benefit to using them, explain them in the alert asking for permission (i.e Tip! Using push notifications may help you  . . . ) rather than just asking in your typical way at the start.

Comment: Unlike many other permissions, it is not possible to customize the alert for notifications.

Comment: Oh! did not know that, thanks for the heads up.